# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS slow after using Zoom

Tags: 20.04

I am using the kernel `5.8.0-53-generic` with 20.04.2.0 and have 500GB SSD and 16GB ram. Every time I use zoom not only during the zoom session is my computer slow but afterward the slowness continues. The only solution I have had is just restarting my computer. When I am using zoom, the fan always turns on and then continues to stay on after ending the zoom session. This also goes away after restarting my computer.

Any suggestions/recommendations would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the running processes on your computer after a Zoom call to see if there’s something consuming excessive resources? `glances` or `htop` are two options to examine this information …

Comment: Yea I tried but nothing out of the usual shows up